# Regular expression for removing one space

Tags: c#, regex

What is the regular expression for removing ONE space? 
e.g:

```
H e l l o  W o r l d  ---->  Hello World
```

(Notice that there's still one space in between Hello World.  It has two space in between to begin with)

FYI, I'm working with C# regex:
Previously I did something like this, but it doesn't work properly for the above case:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}");
pattern.Replace(content, @" ")
```

Comment: (Someone hided this answer) Why do you need regexp here? Can't you just do `content.Replace(" ", "")` using [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=VS.80).aspx) by strings

Comment: @Ivan That will remove all spaces.

Comment: Are you reading a `UTF-16` file as `UTF-8` or `ASCII`?

Comment: @Ivan: That would give "HelloWorld" for his example, not "Hello World". He only wants to remove one space if there is a sequence of multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: Should four spaces in a row result in two spaces? If so it seems that none of the current answers does that.

Comment: @Jonas Elfström: Yes, the question was not clear and I just chose one interpretation.  I will add that interpretation to my answer as well, though I'm not sure which was intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove one space from all groups of one or spaces, use

```
pattern = Regex.Replace(content, " ( *)", "$1");
```

To change *n* spaces to floor(*n*/2) spaces, use

```
pattern = Regex.Replace(content, " ( ?)", "$1");
```

I tried to add examples but stackoverflow consolidates whitespace even in inline code spans it seems.

---

Explanation, as requested: The first finds a space followed by zero or more spaces and replaces it with the zero or more spaces, reducing the length by 1.  The second finds each group of one or two spaces and replaces it by zero or one spaces, changing 1 to 0 in one replacement, 2 to 1 in one replacement, 3 to 2 in two replacements, etc.

Comment: @Victor I've tried to understand regex many a times and failed. My conclusion is it's some form of witchcraft...

Comment: @w69rdy: Don't spill my secrets or I'll put another needle in your doll. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a negative look ahead.

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\s(?!\s)");
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Replace(content, ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to remove exactly one space for each occurrence of one or more consecutive spaces.

For that you need to create a regex which matches each such occurrence putting all but one of the spaces into a capturing group and then replace each occurrence with capturing group. So if there are 2 spaces next to each other, they're found as one match and the second space goes in the capturing group. So after the replacement two spaces have been reduced to one space.

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@" ( *)");
String newString = pattern.Replace("H e l l o  W o r l d", "$1");
// newString == "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

Matches a whitespace followed by a non-whitespace and removes those whitespaces.

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\s)(\S)", @"$2");
```

It kind of looks like it's a string with an added space after each character. If it's so then you could get the original string by retrieving only the even indexed characters in the string.

```
var input = "H e l l o   W o r l d ";
var res = String.Join("", input.Where((c, i) => (i % 2) == 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use a match evaluator to use a two character match:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("H e l l o  W o r l d", @"\s\S", x => x.Value[1].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

By no means a general solution given the nature of your problem, but in this particular case it looks as though you could get away with removing spaces that touch a word character on either side: on the left, for example:

```
Regex.Replace(content, " \b", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

The expression "[\s]{1}" should do it